# Why Can't Assign Object Created With new to Generic Object Reference in Java?

Tags: java, generics, new-operator

I tried to assign object created with `new` to `generic object reference` in Java as in code given below:

```java
interface MyInterface {
    public void myMethod();
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

class MyGeneric<T extends MyInterface> {
    private T obj;

    MyGeneric() {
        this.obj = new MyClass();
    }
    
    MyGeneric(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void callMyMethod() {
        obj.myMethod();
    }
}

class Why {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGeneric<MyClass> mg = new MyGeneric<MyClass>();
        
        mg.callMyMethod();
    }
}
```

when I tried to compile above given code using `javac 17.0.8` I got following error:

```bash
[kunalsharma@fedora ch14]$ javac Why.java 
Why.java:15: error: incompatible types: MyClass cannot be converted to T
        this.obj = new MyClass();
                   ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends MyInterface declared in class MyGeneric
1 error
```

I tried googling it but didn't found any answer.
I am still learning Java so Am I missing something?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are encountering a compilation error because you are trying to assign an instance of `MyClass` directly to a field of type `T` within the `MyGeneric` class, and the compiler is unable to guarantee that `MyClass` is compatible with the type parameter `T`.

To fix this issue, you can modify the constructor of the `MyGeneric` class to accept an object of type `T` and then assign it to the `obj` field. Here's the modified code:

```java
interface MyInterface {
    public void myMethod();
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

class MyGeneric<T extends MyInterface> {
    private T obj;

    MyGeneric() {
        // You can remove this constructor if not needed
    }

    MyGeneric(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void callMyMethod() {
        obj.myMethod();
    }
}

class Why {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGeneric<MyClass> mg = new MyGeneric<>(new MyClass());
        mg.callMyMethod();
    }
}
```

In the modified code, the `MyGeneric` class now has a constructor that takes an object of type `T` and assigns it to the `obj` field. When creating an instance of `MyGeneric` in the `main` method, you can pass an instance of `MyClass` to the constructor, and it should work without any compilation errors.

Comment: hey @justinbitter thanks for responding, but Code was purposefully designed to test why can't compiler guarantee that `MyClass` is compatible with `T` as upper bound on `T` is `MyInterface` and `MyClass` does implements `MyInterface`.

Comment: @KunalSharma If you created a `MyGeneric<OtherClass>`, the `MyClass` wouldn't be compatible to `T`, so the default constructor would be incorrectly assigning.

Comment: "*In the modified code, the MyGeneric class now has a constructor that takes an object of type T and assigns it to the obj field.*" I'm confused--OP had that code already (the `private T obj;` line). Not sure this line belongs in your answer.